# PHPUnit: bootstrap not being executed?

Tags: php, phpunit

When running a test, my phpunit.xml is being loaded by PHPUnit. I can see it in the console as  `--bootstrap` parameter, but it seems like it's not being executed?

In the xml I set `bootstrap="bootstrap.php"`
Is it normal that the xml file contents are echoed just below the `line Testing started at...` and just above `PHPUnit 3.7.21 by Sebastian Bergmann.`?
Any way in my bootstrap.php file I just put

```
die "bootstrap executed";
```

But never see that. What could be wrong?

Edit: This is the contents of phpunit.xml:

```
<phpunit bootstrap="./bootstrap.php">
</phpunit>
```

Comment: a config file(.xml) would be nice to see

Comment: and the config is located in the same folder as the bootstrap file?

Comment: Yes phpunit.xml and bootstrap.php are in the same folder.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to launch the phpunit in one of the following example:

```
#for load a bootstrap php file (with full path and file extension)
>phpunit --bootstrap bootstrap.php
```

or

```
#for load with your xml configuration
>phpunit -c phpunit.xml
```

Hope this help

Comment: but then whas it the attribute "bootstrap="" for? Why can it be set if Phpunit ignores that?